# Guardar en base de datos los txt

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quiero guardar los valores enteros  y booleanos en la bd pero no me da error de codigo solo me lanza el messagebox de "Hubo un error, porfavor intente de nuevo."
txt a guardar son:

```
TxtMinuteGrouping2, TxtCommandGrouping, TxtGroupingRelease.
```

este es mi funcion de SaveConfiguration()

```
 private void SaveConfiguration()
        {
            try
            {

               this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupCommands = Int32.Parse(this.TxtCommandGrouping.Text);
                this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupMinutes = Int32.Parse(this.TxtMinuteGrouping.Text);
                this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.IsReleaseGroupedComms = this.TxtGroupingRelease.Text;

                this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupCommands = Int32.Parse(this.TxtCommandGrouping.Text);
                this.TextMessage = "La configuración fue guardada con éxito.";
                this.ShowMessageForm();
                this.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                this.TextMessage = "Hubo un error, porfavor intente de nuevo.";
                this.ShowMessageForm();
            }
        }
```

*AQUI BIZKITCHENNEWCONFIGURATION*

```
namespace Parrot.Kitchen.Business.Entities.Model
{
     public class BizKitchenNEWConfiguration
    {
        public int GroupMinutes { get; set; }
        public int GroupCommands { get; set; }
        public string IsReleaseGroupedComms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: saca el try, catch, y fijate cual es el error real que te esta tirando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si los `TextBox` estan vacios o no tienen un valor numerico correcto, va a fallar si realizar el `Int32.Parse()`

Para que pase sin problema definiendo un valor por defecto deberias usar el `int.TryParse()`, algo como esto

```
int32.TryParse(this.TxtCommandGrouping.Text, out this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupCommands);
```

la idea es que intente convertir, pero sino puede hacerlo no falla dejando un valor por defecto en la propiedad

Tambien puedes validarlo

```
int commandGrouping = 0;
if(int32.TryParse(this.TxtCommandGrouping.Text, out commandGrouping ))
{
   this.bizKitchenNEWConfiguration.GroupCommands = commandGrouping;
}
```

si puede convertir asigna el valor